# caffe param set twice?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I came across the following structure:

```
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
```

1) Can someone please explain why "param" has set twice?

2) and for fine-tuning I have to set all to 0, right (I do not want this layer change)?

3) should I change these only in train_val.prototxt or also in deploy.prototxt too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first `param` controls the weights and the second controls the
   bias.
2. You may or may not want to set them all to zero. When you do, you are "freezing" this layer, which means its weights and bias won't be updated at all. Another thing you could do is to reduce the `lr_mult` and `decay_mult`, decreasing how drastic the optimizer would update them.
3. Only in training, since, in testing, there is no optimization.